# Image Crud thumbnails display error

Tags: image, thumbnails, crud

Im using IMAGE CRUD to handle a images gallery, upload is correct, insert into table is correct but displaying thumnbails images is wrong, this is an example of the url for image thumbnails that IMAGE CRUD generates:

```
 <img src="http://localhost/macoutlet/http://localhost/macoutlet/assets/uploads/thumb__http://localhost/macoutlet/http://localhost/macoutlet/assets/uploads/673d7-kim-kardashian-gingerly.jpg" class="basic-image" height="60" width="90">
```

Does anyone know the reason or how can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Dont know the reason, maybe because of htaccess rewrite or similar.

Fix: in file /application/libraries/image_crud.php around line 373 find this line:

```
$results[$num]->thumbnail_url = base_url().$this->image_path.'/'.$this->thumbnail_prefix.$row->{$this->url_field};
```

and replace with:

```
$thumbUrlBugFix = explode('/', $row->{$this->url_field});           
$results[$num]->thumbnail_url = base_url().$this->image_path.'/'.$this->thumbnail_prefix.end($thumbUrlBugFix);
```